# How to provoke a googlemaps markerclick event in xamarin android c#?

Tags: c#, android, google-maps

Update:

---

now I have the following issue; mMap.SetOnMarkerClickListener((IOnMarkerClickListener) this); Doesn't seem to work. It tells me that the (IOnMarkerClickListener) cast is not allowed. I tried entering just "this", but then it tells me that the mainactivity can not be converted to a IOnMarkerClickListener.

---

I can't figure out how to make markers clickable in Xamarin android.

In the onMapReady I have placed:

mMap.SetOnMarkerClickListener((IOnMarkerClickListener) this);

However, according to some google search results, I need to override the onMarkerClick event that comes with googleMaps.

However, when I try to override this method it "Couldn't find a suitable method".

Can someone put a c# example of how to make markers clickable please?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: IOnClickListener is an interface, not an abstract class. You do not override it, you simply add a method with the signature `public bool OnMarkerClick (Marker marker){ }`. Make sure that your Activity or Fragment implements the IOnMarkerClickListener interface as well.

Comment: Have a look at the code here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/GooglePlayServices/GooglePlayServices/Source/MarkerDemoActivity.cs

Comment: Thanks, I want to try that, but now I have the following issue;

mMap.SetOnMarkerClickListener((IOnMarkerClickListener) this);

Doesn't seem to work. It tells me that the (IOnMarkerClickListener) cast is not allowed. I tried entering just "this", but then it tells me that the mainactivity can not be converted to a IOnMarkerClickListener.

Comment: Look at the class definition, it needs to implement the `GoogleMap.IOnMarkerClickListener` interface.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I learned something! :)